# conditional sentence construction

Tags: conditional-constructions

I am not sure about the answer I got in me earliar question. I am asking about every day activity.

Please help me with following sentence construciton. I want to use two conditions using if and would.

Senario is our office bus is not passing near from my bosss residence hence he prefer to travel by train every day. I want to ask him if Office Bus route is near from his residence or bus passes near from his residence, then would he travel by bus instade of train every day.

So if i say

1)Would you travel by train if our office bus passes near from your home. or 2)Would you travel by train if our office bus would pass near from your home. or 3)would you travel by train if our office bus is passing near from your home.

Comment: The linked question has an answer which is about a habitual, everyday activity.

Comment: This is at least the third time that I see this exact scenario pass by. There either is a very stubborn boss around somewhere, and this is the third person trying to convince the guy to take the bus, or this is a standard exercise in some course book that somehow gets everyone that encounters it to throw it on this site... Although, this is the same question by the _same user_. This seems to be a recurring problem anyway. I strongly suggest to let the guy travel how he wants. He is the boss after all.